# Does "we" count as a subject in the subject and verb agreement?

Tags: nouns, subject-verb-agreement, clauses, commas

As in this sentence -

> We share in the anger and frustration of our supporters and would like to assure them that we are working to conclude the matter in the best interests of Sunderland AFC.

That was an official statement, but shouldn't there be a comma before the *and*? Then *working* would be the verb and *we* the subject?

Comment: you add the comma if the part after the and is a independent clause (A full sentence on its own). "We X and Y" vs. We X, and we Y"

Comment: pretty sure it's optional though

Comment: A comma is certainly possible there, but I don't see it as required. I have no idea why the presence or absence of a comma has any relevance to whether "we" is a subject (yes, both times) or whether "working" is a verb (no, it is part of the verbal expression "are working").

Comment: A comma would be required after "and" if you had written, "and we had."  Since what follows "and" isn't a clause unto itself, meaning that it doesn't have its own self-contained subject-verb but is using the subject from the subject-verb from earlier in the main clause, no comma is called for before "and."

Comment: @ColinFine From what I have studied online, a comma should always go before "and" when the following is an independent clause? An independent clause follows in the statement, does it not? Why isn't it there? Also, could you explian to me why "working" is a verb but "are working" isn't?

Comment: I can read the sentence out with or without a break after supporters, and so I assert that it a comma is optional.  I have no interest in the arbitrary rules somebody may have invented for when the must or must not be a comma. And I said that "working" was not a verb (though it is a part of  verb) but the it is part of the verbal expression "is working". I have no objection if you call "is working" a verb, but I usually understand "verb" to mean a single word.

Comment: Like @Colin, I can read the sentence out with or without a break after 'supporters'; I see no confusion generated in either case, and see no adjustment in meaning, and hence agree that a comma is optional. Though one might well aid the speaker's breathing. And again, I have no interest in the arbitrary rules somebody may have invented for when there must or must not be a comma. They probably made/make a lot of sense with most/many examples, but slavish adherence to them is misunderstanding how English works and changes.

Comment: A comma is optional. It is essentially a coordination of two VPs with the common subject "we": "We [share in the anger and frustration of our supporters] and [would like to assure them that we are working to conclude the matter in the best interests of Sunderland AFC]. The brackets elements are coordinated VPs.

Comment: @BillJ I was led to believe that a subject and predicate is an independent clause, which then requires a comma. "We" is the subject and then "working" is the predicate no? Can you explain in laymans terms what a coordinated VPs is, please?

Comment: At the top level, the two verb phrases (VPs) that I bracketed in my first message form the predicates; they are called coordinated because they are linked by the coordinating conjunction “and”. It’s rather like a coordination of two main clauses, except that there is only one subject, “we”. The verbs in the two coordinates are “share” and would like to assure”. “That we are working …” is a separate subordinate (dependent) clause embedded in the second coordinate, functioning as complement to “assure” It has no bearing on whether a comma is required or not.

Answer (score 1):

When "and" links two words or phrases, a comma is not necessary. In this sentence, "and" is linking only the two phrases "we share" and "(we) would like to assure," so a comma is not necessary. The phrase "that we are working" is the beginning of a dependent clause.

If it helps, the structure of the sentence is like this:

- We share in the anger and frustration of our supporters.
- We would like to assure them.

  - We are working to conclude the matter.